# crystal report replace function

Tags: crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2, report, crystal-reports-2008

I have two tables:

```
Table 1:

Id stringval
-- ---------
1  do you work on date XXXX  and date @@@@

Table 2:

Id  CharString  ValueString
--  ----------  -----------
1   XXXX        5-5-2013
2   @@@@        10-5-2013
```

I want to return the following string value:
**do you work on date 5-5-2013 and date 10-5-2013**

Can this be achieved using Crystal Reports?

Or, can it be achieved using Sql Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `XXXX`, `@@@@`, or any other values in the `CharString` column of `Table2` would only appear as placeholders it is also possible to achieve your goal using sql server. A query like this would do it:

```
DECLARE @CharString VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ValueString VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ResultString VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @SearchString = stringval FROM Table1
SELECT @ResultString = stringval FROM Table1

DECLARE c CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT CharString, ValueString 
    FROM Table2

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @CharString, @ValueString

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%' + @CharString + '%', @SearchString) <> 0
        SET @ResultString = REPLACE(@ResultString, @CharString, @ValueString)

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @CharString, @ValueString
END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c

SELECT @ResultString
```

Answer (score 0):

The option here would be take the string value from table and manuplate the string the using string functions of crystal reports.

I am not sure how this will work but give a try.

1. take **do you work on date XXXX  and date @@@@** into a string and split by space then extact **XXXX** and **@@@@** now take the required values **5-5-2013** and **10-5-2013** in to varaibles now join the strings like

   "do you work on data "+5-5-2013+" and date "+10-5-2013